# Why doesn't "case" with "when > 2" work?

Tags: ruby

Why is this not working?

```
case ARGV.length
  when 0
    abort "Error 1"
  when > 2
    abort "Error 2"
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `if` statement would probably be more fitting for your code, since you don't have a definitive range/value, but rather just a greater-than:

```
if ARGV.length == 0
  abort "Error 1"
elsif ARGV.length > 2
  abort "Error 2"
end
```

Answer (score 51):

It's not valid ruby syntax.

What you need is

```
case
  when ARGV.length == 0
    abort "Error 1"
  when ARGV.length > 2
    abort "Error 2"
end
```

When you write `case x`, the important part you need to understand is that ruby takes the x and then applies a comparison to the argument or expressions you insert in the `when` clause.

The line where you say `when x >2` reads to ruby like:

```
if ARGV.length == > 2
```

When you remove a specific object from the `case` statements, you can apply conditionals within the `when` statements .

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 + irb 0.9.5 reports (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected '>' with the OP's original instruction set. My answer includes a working rewritten instruction set.

Comment: I tried it out in a .rb file, it does show a syntax error then. *&^^%&^ IRB.

Comment: Actually what's annoying here is that I cannot find definitive documentation to support my claim, I just happen to *know* the answer. rubyspec.org and ruby-doc.org aren't being helpful. The language syntax specs I can find don't seem to cover this case.

Comment: Actually, technically it reads as: `if 2 === > ARGV.length` - case statements use the tripple-equals operator on the argument to the `when` keyword, and they supply the `case` keyword's argument as value to compare itself to.

Comment: I didn't know you could use a case statement that is blank on the case line?!?  I had a similar issue to @emurad in that I was trying to evaluate hitdice so I had case hitdice and I was trying to say when hitdice >= chance_to_hit (making a game).  Although Rubocop in Rubymine is now complaining that I am using a blank case statement and I should use if instead.  I think case is far more elegant and easier to read in some cases no pun intended.

Answer (score 25):

Use `1.0 / 0.0` to get infinity, which fixes @mosch's code:

```
case ARGV.length
  when 0
    raise "Too few"
  when 3..(1.0/0.0)
    raise "Too many"
end
```

You don't have to be Chuck Norris to divide by a floating point zero.

Comment: Instead of `(1.0 / 0.0)` we can use `Float::INFINITY`, which was added in ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: The parentheses around 1.0/0.0 seem redundant as ".." has lower precedence than "/". +1 for the Chuck Norris reference.

Answer (score 19):

Well, it doesn't work because it's not valid ruby syntax. However, you can do this:

```
x = 15
case x
  when 0..9 then puts "good"
  when 10..12 then puts "better"
  when 13..200 then puts "best"
  else
    puts "either great or poor"
end
```

Comment: Yours is the only answer that makes sense to me - truly idiomatic and elegant. It's what I have used as well.

Comment: You can also use newlines instead of "then"

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `if elsif` or `lambda/proc` (`then` notation is just for shortness):

```rb
case x
when 1 then '1'
when ->(a) { a > 2 } then '>2'
end
```

You can also create a named variable for clarity:

```rb
greater_than_2 = ->(a){ a > 2 }

case x
when 1 then '1'
when greater_than_2 then '>2'
end
```

You can also create your own comparison predicate:

```
greater_than = ->(n) { ->(a) {a > n} }

case x
when 1 then '1'
when greater_than[2] then '>2'
when greater_than[5] then '>5'
end
```

Answering your initial question `when > 1` is not a valid syntax, since `>` is binary operator in Ruby, which is to say its arity 2, meaning it takes 2 arguments. Don't be confused of term binary vs bitwise.